# I want to delete multiple images from source folder through PHP but the code for deleting the multiple images from the folder is not working

Tags: php

```
    <?php include("header.php"); ?>
    <?php 
    if (@$_POST['delete']=="Delete"){
        $count=count($_POST['delbx']);
        for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){
            $delete = "DELETE FROM admin WHERE a_id='".$_POST['delbx'][$i]."'";
            $resulty = mysqli_query($conn, $delete) or die(mysql_error());
            $select_delete = "SELECT `a_image` FROM admin WHERE a_id='".$_POST['delbx'][$i]."'";
            $resultrowdy = $conn->query($select_delete);
            $rowdy = $resultrowdy->fetch_assoc();
            $path="admin/".$rowdy['a_image'];
            echo $path;
            unlink($path);
            echo '<script>window.location="view_user.php"</script>';
        }   
    } ?>

    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table">
            <caption>All Users</caption>
            <?php
            $sql = "SELECT a_id, a_name, a_phone, a_password, a_role, a_mail, a_image FROM admin";
            $result = $conn->query($sql);

            if ($result->num_rows > 0) {?>
                <thead>
                    <tr>  
                        <th><form action="view_user.php" method="post"><input name="delete" type="submit" id="delete" value="Delete"></th><th>S. No.</th> <th>Name</th> <th>Phone No.</th> <th>Mail Id</th> <th>Role</th> <th>Password</th> <th>Image</th> 
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <?php
                while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
                    <tbody> 
                        <tr>
                             <th scope="row">
                                 <?php echo $row["a_id"]; ?>
                             </th>
                             <td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
                                 <input name="delbx[]" type="checkbox" id="delbx[]" value="<?php echo $row["a_id"]; ?>" />
                             </td>
                             <td>
                                 <?php echo $row["a_name"]; ?>
                             </td>
                             <td>
                                 <?php echo $row["a_phone"]; ?>
                             </td>
                             <td>
                                 <?php  echo $row["a_mail"]; ?>
                             </td>
                             <td>
                                 <?php echo $row["a_role"]; ?>
                             </td>
                             <td>
                                 <?php echo $row["a_password"]; ?>
                             </td>
                             <td>
                                 <img src="admin/<?php echo $row["a_image"]; ?>" width="60" height="40">
                             </td>
                             <th>
                                 <a href="admin_update.php?editid=<?php echo $row["a_id"];?>" style="color:#FFF;">Edit</a>
                             </th>
                         </tr> 
                     </tbody> 
            <?php 
                }
            } else {
                echo "0 results";
            }?>
            </table>
        </form>
    </div>
    <?php include("footer.php"); ?>
```

The code I mention is not deleting the multiple images from the source folder but deleting the multiple data from database whereas I am trying to delete images from the source folder along with data please help thanks in advance

Comment: You have to queue your database for the exact filenames before you can proceed with deleting.

Comment: unlink($conn, $path); i tried this but not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the problem is you are deleting the row and trying to select image column from the deleted row.. **dont use user supplied variables directly in your query**

your code should be

```
    for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){
      $select_delete = "SELECT `a_image` FROM admin WHERE a_id='".$_POST['delbx'][$i]."'";
      $resultrowdy = $conn->query($select_delete);
      $rowdy = $resultrowdy->fetch_assoc();

      $delete = "DELETE FROM admin WHERE a_id='".$_POST['delbx'][$i]."'";
      if(mysqli_query($conn, $delete)){
        $path="admin/".$rowdy['a_image'];
        unlink($path);
        echo '<script>window.location="view_user.php"</script>';  
      }
    }
```

Comment: got it sir , i have to select the image coloumn first before the delete query and then delete the data ??

Comment: @v Sugumar  thank you sir for teaching me 1 important lesson :)